# Google Maps wont work under Mobile Mode of Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-chrome

The problem is that Google Map does not opening under Google Chrome of Android device (updated to last version).

Under the PC version of Google Chrome it works like a sharm.

The code is a standart map snippet to display a map's marker. So under the mobile Google Chrome I see a blank screen.

**But it works when I turn on Google Chrome to the PC mode.**

What do I missi to config Google Maps to work under Mobile Mode of Google Chrome?

```
function initMap() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: initialZoom,
            center: locCompany,
            streetViewControl: false, 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locCompany,
            map: map,

            icon: '@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.png")'
        });

          map.setZoom(initialZoom);
    }
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve this issue.

I relocated

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```

into end of `body` tag of `Layout` page.

And in the map page I put `initMap` function into `header` like

```
@section head{
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 70vh !important;
        } 
    </style>
    <script>
         function initMap() {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: initialZoom,
                center: locCompany,
                  streetViewControl: false,

                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                gestureHandling: 'greedy',
                 zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                }
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: locCompany,
                map: map,
                icon: '@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.png")'
            });
            map.setZoom(initialZoom);
        }
    </script>
}
```